# where can i find Java JMF tutorial

Tags: java, video, webcam, jmf

I'd like to know about basic classes for playing video from webcam

I'd also like to play with video buffers pixels

where can i find a Java JMF tutorial that will help me achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JMF API](https://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/)

http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060422/PlayingVideowithJMF/

Answer (score 2):

I liked the [Program multimedia with JMF](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-04-2001/jw-0406-jmf1.html) 2-part ([second part here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2001/jw-0504-jmf2.html)) series a lot when first experimenting with the framework.