# extracting image from a video in java

Tags: java, frameworks, media

i want to know how can i extract images from a video using JMF.

Comment: Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402459/where-can-i-find-java-jmf-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

```
Player player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(cdi.getLocator());
player.start();
FrameGrabbingControl frameGrabber = (FrameGrabbingControl) player.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");


//////////////////////////////

private Image grab() {
Buffer buf = frameGrabber.grabFrame();
// Convert frame to an buffered image so it can be processed and saved
Image img = (new BufferToImage((VideoFormat) buf.getFormat()).createImage(buf));
    return img;
}
```

for more info see complete example: http://www.comp.rgu.ac.uk/staff/fh/CM4062/mis/jmf/FrameGrab.html