# Extract images from mp4 using java

Tags: java, mp4

I want to write code in java to extract the images in a mp4 file. Kindly guide me how to go about it. I am totally clueless.

Comment: possible duplicate of [extracting image from a video in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376656/extracting-image-from-a-video-in-java)

Comment: @npinti That question refers specifically to JMF which (out of the box) does not support MP4.

Answer (score 2):

Java SE has Java Media Framework (JMF) but it provides support for only a few video [formats](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html), not including MPEG-4.

Of course, you have some third-party choices to achieve your goal. One of them is [Jffmpeg](http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/). It is an extension to JMF which contains support for MPEG-4.

Xuggler is another good choice with GPL/LGPL license. It works on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

Comment: I recently had some good experiences with Jffmpeg while making high compression videos for [my tube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/DrewTubeish/videos).

Answer (score 1):

[Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/documentation) is an open-source third party library you can use to do this.  Read through the API's. and sample code.